# Reference to figure inside minipage

Tags: floats, cross-referencing

I want to reference to a figure inside a minipage but it won't work. The structure looks something like this:

```
\ref{fig:test}
\begin{figure}
\begin{minipage}
blablabla
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}
\includegraphics{fig:test}
\caption{test}
\end{minipage}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

The error I get is: Reference `fig:test' on page x undefined
Where do I place the label in order to get the reference to work?

Comment: Your minipage has no width argument, this won't compile. Correcting and putting the label inside of the minipage, it will work

Comment: And please post compilable documents, not just fragments!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user1234".

Answer (score 4):

Apart from the usefulness of `minipage` here, there are two errors:

- `\begin{minipage}{10cm}` (or any other width), but the width was missing here (in both `minipage` usages) -- this will to a syntactical error.
- The `\label` must be placed within the `minipage`, not outside -- this is because `\label` reuses the `\@currentlabel` macro which is a `\protected@edef`ined macro and this gets lost outside of the group established by `minipage` -- in order to prevent this, use `\label` inside this group!

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

In Figure \ref{fig:test} we see a beautiful duck!
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}{10cm}
    blablabla
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}{10cm}
    \includegraphics{ente}
    \caption{test}
\label{fig:test}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Tnx for your answer. However, when I try this the reference still doesn't work correctly. Could there be any other reasons as to why this happens? As a sidenote, I left the width of the minipage out as I thought that wasn't necessary for the question.

Comment: Okay, I have found something else. The whole document is inside a appendices environment. Now I have pasted this code above in between two existing chapters. But now references in the appendix after the pasted code is not updating its references. For example: Appendix B has become appendix C. However, figure B.1 still is called B.1.

Comment: @user108420: Please update your code to a compilable version, anything else is only guess work!